# Game theory question concerning notation

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

What exactly is being talked about here?

[image]

"g(x) = the largest power of 2 dividing x".

When x is 12, we get that g(x) = 4. The largest power of 2 to divide 12 is not 4 ($16$) it would be $2^2$ or 4. 8 does not divide 12, neither does 16.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You didn't notice that all the values in the $g(x)$ row were powers of 2?

Comment: This seems more a terminology question than anything else. In English, a "power of 2" is $2^n$ for some $n$, whereas you'd have to say something more awkward like "the exponent of the largest power of 2" if you wanted to refer to the quantity you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

$g(x)$ is equal to the actual power of 2, not the exponent. So $4=2^{2}$, which is the largest power of two dividing $12$.

Comment: ah, I see. Thank you.